# Validar si mi localización esta dentro de un Radio y obtener fecha/hora - Flutter

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, flutter, geolocalización

Necesito **validar mi Ubicacion cuando entre a un Radio y obtener la fecha y hora**, es una app en flutter estoy usando las libreria de google_maps_flutter para mostrar el mapa.

soy nuevo usando flutter, cualquier ayuda es buena, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías revisar este package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geofence

Comment: revisare, gracias @diegoveloper